# Using composer with wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, composer-php

I am building my own Wordpress Skeleton "Application". Within this application i have the following files:

- composer.phar
- composer.json
- index.php
- wp-config.php
- wp-content
- wordpress (composed by composer)

This is the composer.json of this repo: https://raw.github.com/Gizburdt/Wordpress-Conductor/master/composer.json

The thing is: Gizburdt/scaffold is installed within the vendor folder and not within the wp-content/themes/ folder. Here is the composer.json from Gizburdt/scaffold: https://raw.github.com/Gizburdt/Wordpress-Scaffold/master/composer.json

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're overriding the "magic" done by composer/installer for packages of type wordpress-plugin or wordpress-theme by including them in your json as a package.

Instead of this:

```
{
    "type": "package",
    "package": {
    "name": "gizburdt/scaffold",
    "version": "dev-master",
    "source": {
        "url": "https://github.com/Gizburdt/Wordpress-Scaffold.git",
        "type": "git",
        "reference": "origin/master"
    }
    }
},
```

Install it as type VCS repo - then it will read the type correctly from the composer.json in the Wordpress-Scaffold project:

```
{
    "type": "vcs",
    "url": "https://github.com/Gizburdt/Wordpress-Scaffold.git"
},
```